# How to calculate two input form fields and put the value in another using JS and submit button?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I know this is an extremely basic question, but I just couldn't find anything useful on the internet. I have 2 input boxes and I want calculate that input and put the result in output using submit button and navigating by form id.

```
<script>
function Calculate()
{

  var resources = GetFieldValue( "Resources" );
  var minutes = GetFieldValue( "Minutes" ); 
  var permin = parseFloat(resources) / 60;
  var result = parseFloat(permin) * parseFloat(minutes);
</script>
```

Comment: By *submit* are you talking about POST submit to the server? and by *output* you're referring to what?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik No just a basic run in a html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body>
<input type='text' id='Resources'/>
<input type='text' id='Minutes' onblur='Calculate();'/>
<form name ="testarea" Method="Get" Action="youpage.html" id='form1'>
<input type='text' id='answer' name='ans' />
</form>
</body>
<script>


function Calculate()
{
  var resources = document.getElementById('Resources').value;
  var minutes = document.getElementById('Minutes').value; 
  var permin = parseFloat(resources) / 60;
  document.getElementById('answer').value=parseFloat(permin) * parseFloat(minutes);
  document.form1.submit();
}
</script>
```

Your form will submit and your answer is in the url like

```
youpage.html?ans=youranswer
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the HTML button tag :
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

```
<button onClick="Calculate();" value="calculate">
```

in the function Calculate instead of GetFieldValue use

```
document.getElementbyId("Resources").value;
```

where

```
<input type="text" id="Resources">
```

use

```
document.getElementbyId("Result").value = result;
```

to fill in another input element.